# verificação de UITextField com somente numero

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uitableviewcell

estou criando uma tableview com Cells custon via xib e UITableViewCell e tenho um cell que possui apenas uma textField e quero fazer um verificação de quantidade de caracteres e numeros para esse textfield porem eu não sei fazer isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o delegate do UITextField

**Implementação em Objective-c:**

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Dentro desse método você pode verificar o tipo de valor que esta recebendo:

```
NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];

if(!(([string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet].length > 0) || [string isEqualToString:@""])) {
    return NO;
}
```

Para limitar a quantidade de caracteres basta pegar a string do campo `[[textField text] lenght]`

---

**Implementação em Swift:**

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let nonNumberSet:NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet();

    if count(string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(nonNumberSet)) > 0 {
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}
```

A implementação em Objective-c é de um aplicativo que desenvolvi, o de Swift não cheguei testar 100%, mas aparentemente esta funcionando.